# Look up all classes that includes Enumerable module in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to get a list of all classes that include `Enumerable`. Can I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all `Module`s currently in the object memory (note, however, that this may include `Module`s that are no longer reachable but haven't been garbage collected yet) with `ObjectSpace.each_object(Module)` and since `each_object` like all other iteration methods returns an `Enumerator` (which itself mixes in `Enumerable`), we can simply `select` those `Module`s which `include?` the `Enumerable` module in their `ancestors` list:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).select {|m| m.include?(Enumerable) }
# => [Process::Tms, Enumerator::Generator, Enumerator::Lazy, Enumerator, 
#     ObjectSpace::WeakMap, Dir, File, ARGF.class, IO, Range, Struct, Hash, 
#     Array]
```

Answer (score 5):

You may also use `ObjectSpace` module to get list of all classes and modules. Put additional check for `Enumerable`

```
require 'set'
enumed = Set.new

ObjectSpace.each_object { |o| enumed.add(o) if [Class, Module].include?(o.class) && o.include?(Enumerable) }
puts enumed.to_a
```

Comment: Thank you. Did not know ObjectSpace. : )